# How to create Singleton OkHtpp Class and handle previous requests

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm using Google Autocomplete Places API with android and what I'm trying to do is:

1. Every time the user type a char inside of the EditText it needs to make a new request to get the predictions results.
2. I need to cancel the previous request because the only result that I need is the final address/location the user typed.
3. And then work out with some logic to clean the RecyclerView if the location length is less then 3 chars.

That's why I need a singleton instance, I tried this :

```
public class OkHttpSingleton extends OkHttpClient {
private static  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public static OkHttpClient getInstance() {
    return client;
}

public OkHttpSingleton() {}

public void CloseConnections(){
    client.dispatcher().cancelAll();
}
public List<PlacePredictions> getPredictions(){
    //// TODO: 26/09/2017  do the request!
    return null;
}
```

}

But I'm not sure if it is the right way to do, because in the [doc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/) it says that the `dispatcher().cancelAll()` method cancel all the requests But I know that way is wrong! I'm more concerned in how to create a singleton then the rest.

The Main Activity:

```
Address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if(s.length() > 3){
                _Address = Address.getText().toString();
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try { // request...
                    }else{Clear the RecyclerView!}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement a singleton helper class that keeps one `OkHttpClient` and cover all of your custom functionalities using this one particular client:

```
public class OkHttpSingleton {

    private static OkHttpSingleton singletonInstance;

    // No need to be static; OkHttpSingleton is unique so is this.
    private OkHttpClient client;

    // Private so that this cannot be instantiated.
    private OkHttpSingleton() {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build();
    }

    public static OkHttpSingleton getInstance() {
        if (singletonInstance == null) {
            singletonInstance = new OkHttpSingleton();
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }

    // In case you just need the unique OkHttpClient instance.
    public OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void closeConnections() {
        client.dispatcher().cancelAll();
    }

    public List<PlacePredictions> getPredictions(){
        // TODO: 26/09/2017  do the request!
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
OkHttpSingleton localSingleton = OkHttpSingleton.getInstance();
...
localSingleton.closeConnections();
...
OkHttpClient localClient = localSingleton.getClient();
// or
OkHttpClient localClient = OkHttpSingleton.getInstance().getClient();
```

Comment: One more question, how I'm going to access the `closeConnections` and getPredictions() ?

Comment: `localClient.closeConnections()`?

Comment: it's not finding by the object!

Comment: Ah, the problem is that you have `OkHttpClient` instance, not `OkHttpSingleton`. I am adding new code.

Comment: Thanks, cu'z after initialize I need to get the same object to perform the requests!